# jQuery - Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Value is not of type 'long'

Tags: javascript, zxing

I have a video and canvas element like so:

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480"></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

and what I am trying to do is decode a PDF417 barcode from my web cam.

Here is the code that gets the permission to use the web cam:

```
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    });
}
```

And this is where I try to use the camera to capture the barcode and decode it:

```
canvas_context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);

try {

    var source = new ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource(canvas_context, video);

    var binarizer = new ZXing.Common.HybridBinarizer(source);
    var bitmap = new ZXing.BinaryBitmap(binarizer);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(ZXing.PDF417.PDF417Reader.decode(bitmap, null, false), null, 4));

} catch (err) {

    console.log(err);

}
```

However I am getting this error:

> Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Value
>   is not of type 'long'.

On this line:

```
var source = new ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource(canvas_context, video);
```

Which calls this method:

```
ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource = function (bitmap, w, h) {

  var debug = typeof window != 'undefined' && window.__debug === true;
  var width, height;
  if (typeof bitmap == 'number') {
    width = bitmap;
    height = w;
    ZXing.BaseLuminanceSource.call(this, width, height);
  } else {
    var canvas, data;
    if (bitmap instanceof Uint8ClampedArray) {
      width = w;
      height = h;
      data = bitmap;
    } else if (bitmap instanceof ImageData) {
      width = w || bitmap.width;
      height = h || bitmap.height;
      data = bitmap.data;
    } else {
      canvas = w;
      width = canvas.naturalWidth;
      height = canvas.naturalHeight;
      var imageData = bitmap.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
      data = imageData.data;
    }
    ZXing.BaseLuminanceSource.call(this, width, height);

    var stride = Math.abs(data.length / height);

    if (debug) this.debugBitmap = [];
    //console.time("luminances")
    for(var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      var strideOffset = y * stride;

      var maxIndex = (4 * width) + strideOffset;
      for(var x = strideOffset; x < maxIndex; x += 4) {
        var luminance = ((7424 * data[x] + 38550 * data[x + 1] + 19562 * data[x + 2]) >> 16);
        //var alpha = data[x + 3];
        //luminance = (((luminance * alpha) >> 8) + (255 * (255 - alpha) >> 8) + 1);

        //luminance = luminance < 50 ? 1 : (luminance > 90 ? 255 : luminance)

        this.luminances.push(luminance);
        if (debug) {
          this.debugBitmap.push(luminance);
          this.debugBitmap.push(luminance);
          this.debugBitmap.push(luminance);
          this.debugBitmap.push(255);
        }
      }
    }
    //console.timeEnd("luminances")
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This function accepts (among many other things) an HTMLImageElement as `w` parameter, from which it will get its `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties. An HTMLVideoElement doesn't have these properties (but `videoWidth` and `videoHeight`).

So given the complex signature of this function, the easiest might be to pass yourself an ImageData there:

```
const data = canvas_context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);
source = new ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource(data)
```

Comment: I made the adjustment, still getting the same error.

Comment: Would I have to change this: ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource = function (bitmap, w, h) { ?

Comment: No in the case of an ImageData they'll read these this from it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing. In your call to `BitmapLuminanceSource` you use 2 parameters (a canvas context and a video [source]), while the function definition itself uses (bitmap, w, h) as arguments (which a casual reader would interpret as a bitmap, together with its width and height parameters).

Then, you suddenly define a variable with the name of canvas -- but a canvas and its context always go together i.e. if you really needed a canvas object, you would have injected it together with its context.

Next, you assign the input parameter w to this new canvas variable. This is highly confusing, as in the code above you equal w repeatedly to a width parameter.

Assuming w is actually the canvas belonging to the canvas context mentioned earlier, we then come to the gist of your problem: both width and height in your call to `getImageData` are undefined (or zero): the canvas element itself does not have a naturalWidth or naturalHeight property, only an `imageElement` does.

This is what causes the 'Value is not of type 'long'' error notification.